# How do you calculate the SVD when $\Sigma$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

The matrix is

$$\pmatrix{1 &0 &-1\\
-1& 0& 1}$$

The $\Sigma$ matrix I get is

$$\pmatrix{2& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0}$$

which is not invertible, so I can't calculate $U$.

Comment: Why the downvote when the OP is showing the correct $S$?

Comment: We find the first column of $U$ as $u_1 =\begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}$, but we can't find $u_2$ in the same way since $\sigma_2 = 0$. To find $u_2$, we just have to extend $u_1$ to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Letting $u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}$ will work and allow you to continue. Notice that $U = [u_1~~u_2]$ is a rotation matrix.

Comment: im still getting the wrong value for u1, can you explain a bit on how to actually get the value. Also i did not understand how to come to the conclusion of using u2 as the 1/(2**1/2) 1/(2**1/2).

Comment: This question makes no sense. In general, $\Sigma$ is rectangular. Why should it be invertible?