# Dimensions of $U$ in SVD

Tags: matrices, svd

In SVD we have

$$M=U\Sigma V^T$$

where the columns of $U$ are the eigenvectors of $MM^T$.

If $M$ is $m \times n$, is it necessary that $U$ be $m \times m$ or can it be $m \times r$? In other words, is there a case where we do not have a full set of eigenvectors for $M M^T$, because they are linearly dependent or because the eigenvalues are $0$, or for any other reason?

Comment: $M M^\top$ is symmetric and, thus, it has a full set of orthogonal eigenvectors.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks. and in case we have some zero eigenvalues how will we make eigenvectors for them?

Comment: Everything would be easier if you decided whether $M$ is tall or fat. Considering each case separately is better.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Could you give an answer for both?

Comment: If $M$ is tall, find the eigenvalues of $M^\top M$. If $M$ is fat, find the eigenvalues of $M M^\top$. It avoids having to deal with useless zero eigenvalues.

Comment: I have a little confusion here, because if $MM^T$ is symmetric and has m eigenvalue and $M^TM$ is symmetric and has n eigenvalue, then I know that both should have same number and values of eigenvalues and hence we should have only r eigenvalue and I am assuming that they should have same number of eigenvectors like x eigenvector!! please correct me

Comment: That is what I meant by "useless zero eigenvalues". The squared singular values are the nonzero eigenvalues and the non-useless zero eigenvalues.

Comment: I read that for zero eigenvalue you have to come with other eigenvectors as mentioned here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116110/how-do-you-calculate-the-svd-when-sigma-is-not-invertible and not like what you said that "it has a full set of orthogonal eigenvectors" can you check this?

Comment: ok, so you mean when that guy said "we can't find u2 in the same way since σ2=0. To find u2, we just have to extend u1 to an orthonormal basis of R2." he was wrong right? (I mean we must have the full set of orthogonal eigenvectors without the need to introduce anything)

Comment: Where's the difficulty? His matrix is $2 \times 3$. Hence, $U$ is $2 \times 2$. He found an eigenvector. How hard is to find the other eigenvector? It must be orthogonal to the first eigenvector. It must also have unit norm. Hence, there are only 2 options. Pick one.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo by the way his matrix should be $$ \Sigma = \pmatrix{2& 0 & 0\\
0& 0 & 0}$$ because $ \Sigma$ is $m \times n$ right?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo there is also a little confusion for me because when I am calculating the eigenvector when eigenvalue=0 I am getting a correct eigenvector $$\pmatrix{1/\sqrt{2}\\ 
1/\sqrt{2}}$$ so why to complement the set of the orthonormal (if there is any missing vector) instead of calculating them in the normal way?

Comment: Good question. I wonder the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r$ be the rank of $m\times n$ matrix $M$.

Then a typical SVD makes the matrices of the form:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\\ \\ \quad \,M\,\quad\\ \\ \\ \hline\end{array}=
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \\ \\ \quad U_r\quad& \quad U_r^\perp\quad \\ \\ \\ \hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \\ \quad\Sigma_r\quad&0 \\ \\ \hline \\ 0&0 \\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|cc|}\hline\\ \quad\,V_n^{\perp*}\,\quad\\ \\ \hline \quad V_n^*\quad\\\hline\end{array}$$
In this form $U_r$ are orthogonal unit vectors that span the range of $M$, and $U_r^\perp$ forms the completion to an orthonormal basis.
Similarly $V_n$ is a set of orthonormal vectors that spans the null space of $M$, and $V_n^\perp$ completes it to an orthonormal basis.

Note that $U$ is always an $m\times m$ unitary matrix here.

However, we *can* create a so called  *'economic'* SVD as well, which is not the official SVD:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\\ \\ \quad\,M\,\quad\\ \\ \\ \hline\end{array}=
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \\ \\ \quad U_r\quad\\ \\ \\ \hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline \\ \quad\Sigma_r\quad \\ \\\hline\end{array}
\begin{array}{|cc|}\hline\\ \quad\,V_n^{\perp*}\,\quad\\ \\ \hline \end{array}$$

Now $U_r$ is an $m\times r$ matrix. And we have:
$$M=U\Sigma V^*=U_r\Sigma_r V_n^{\perp*}$$
where $U_r$, $\Sigma_r$, and $V_n^{\perp}$ are each of the same full rank $r$.

Comment: Nice explanation. Can we calculate the eigenvectors "as usual" instead of "the completion to an orthonormal basis"? what are the drawbacks of calculating it as usual?

Comment: Yes @MosabShaheen, we can can calculate the eigenvectors as usual. We do need to make sure that we 'choose' the eigenvectors to be perpendicular and of unit length.

Comment: Is there a case where if we calculate them as usual (instead of finding how to complete the set), we may come with wrong vectors?

Comment: Yes @MosabShaheen. If we have a duplicated eigenvalue, it corresponds to multiple eigenvectors that are independent. Normally we are free to pick them however we like. But for SVD we have to pick them orthonormal. The simplest example is the zero matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Any pair of 2 independent vectors are eigenvectors of eigenvalue 0 now, but they do not necessarily form a unitary matrix $U$.

Comment: marked as answer

Comment: In case we have 'economic' SVD you said U is $m \times r$. In this case we are excluding the zero eigenvalues from $\Sigma$ and the corresponding eigenvectors from U and V, right?

Comment: Yes. Eigenvectors for $0$ will be mapped to the zero vector anyway, so we don't 'lose' anything.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks about the four fundamental subspaces. So, start with...

### Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra

A matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$ induces four fundamental subspaces. These are range and null spaces for both the column and the row spaces.
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

$\color{blue}{Range}$ spaces are colored in blue, $\color{red}{null}$ spaces in red.

The singular value decomposition (SVD) provides an orthonormal basis for the four fundamental subspaces.

### Define SVD

Start with a nonzero matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{\rho}$, where the matrix rank $\rho<m$ and $\rho<n$. The singular value decomposition, guaranteed to exist, is
$$
\mathbf{A}
= 
\mathbf{U} \, 
\Sigma \, 
\mathbf{V}^{*} 
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} &
    \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} \\
    \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
  \end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\
    \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array}
\right].
$$
The codomain matrix $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$, and the domain matrix $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ are unitary:
$$
\mathbf{U}^{*}\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{U}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{m}, \quad 
\mathbf{V}^{*}\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{V}\mathbf{V}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{n}.
$$
The column vectors of the domain matrices provide orthormal bases for the four fundamental subspaces:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
%
 matrix & subspace \\\hline
%
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times\rho} & 
     \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)} \\
%
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times\rho} &
     \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left(\mathbf{A}^{*}\right)} \\
%
  \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times m-\rho} &
     \color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A^{*}}\right)} \\
%
  \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n-\rho} &
     \color{red}{\mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}
%
\end{array}
$$
There are $\rho$ singular values which are ordered and real:
$$
  \sigma_{1} \ge \sigma_{2} \ge \dots \ge \sigma_{\rho}>0.
$$
and are the square root of non-zero eigenvalues of the product matrices $\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{*}$.
These singular values form the diagonal matrix of singular values
$$
\mathbf{S} = \text{diagonal} (\sigma_{1},\sigma_{1},\dots,\sigma_{\rho}) \in\mathbb{R}^{\rho\times\rho}.
$$
The $\mathbf{S}$ matrix is embedded in the sabot matrix $\Sigma\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ whose shape insures conformability.

### SVD in terms of vectors

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc}
     \sigma_{1} & 0 & \dots &  &   & \dots &  0 \\
     0 & \sigma_{2}  \\
     \vdots && \ddots \\
       & & & \sigma_{\rho} \\\hline
       & & & & 0 & \\
     \vdots &&&&&\ddots \\
     0 & & &   &   &  & 0 \\
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
     \color{red}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{N}}}^{*}
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
  & =
% U
   \left[ \begin{array}{cccccccc}
    \color{blue}{u_{1}} & \dots & \color{blue}{u_{\rho}} & \color{red}{u_{\rho+1}} & \dots & \color{red}{u_{m}}
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} & \mathbf{0} \\
     \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V
   \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    \color{blue}{v_{1}^{*}} \\ 
    \vdots \\
    \color{blue}{v_{\rho}^{*}} \\
    \color{red}{v_{\rho+1}^{*}} \\
    \vdots \\ 
    \color{red}{v_{n}^{*}}
  \end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

Note that the singular values *only* correspond to $\color{blue}{range}$ space vectors.

The column vectors form spans for the subspaces:
$$
\begin{align} 
% R A
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{u_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{u_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% R A*
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
 \color{blue}{v_{1}}, \dots , \color{blue}{v_{\rho}}
\right\} \\
% N A*
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{u_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{u_{m}}
\right\} \\
% N A
\color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} &=
\text{span} \left\{
\color{red}{v_{\rho+1}}, \dots , \color{red}{v_{n}}
\right\} \\
%
\end{align}
$$

The full SVD provides an orthonormal span for not only the two null spaces, but also both range spaces.